# How do I work out the total circuit Current?

Tags: diodes, current-measurement

[image]

I am trying to work out the circuit current so I can workout the voltages across my resistors but I don't know how to change the diode Which has a 0.6V drop into ohms so i can complete the formula.

What am I doing wrong?

I know the formulas but cant seem to apply any of them because I only have the 1 value of the voltage.

Comment: This looks a lot like homework, what have you tried, what techniques have you learned in your classes?

Answer (score 1):

> "i dont know how to change the diode Which has a 0.6V drop into ohms so i can complete the formula."

You don't need to do that.

Approach the problem as follows (with i being notation for current):

20v = drop across D1 + drop across R1 + drop across D2 + drop across R2
20v = 0.6v + r1*i + 0.6v + r2*i
18.8v = r1*i + r2*i
18.8v = (r1 + r2) * i

Can you now complete the problem using Ohm's laws?

Comment: Omg thanks, Yeah it is homework but im learning though an online university that have been no help at all.

Comment: Just missed the simple step of deducting the volt drops over the diodes before doing the calculation.

Comment: If this has adequately solved your problem you should accept it as an answer to close the question.